# How do you get the country/state/region/city/state/zip/postal from GPS coordinates?

Tags: c#, google-maps, gps, exif, iptc

I have GPS coordinates on all of my photos. I want to include tags/IPTC data for the city, state, zip, etc.. However all I have is the GPS coordinates. How can I take these and get meaningful info in an automated fashion (I have thousands upon thousands of photos, so typing each one into google maps would not work).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do reverse geocoding with Google Maps API using the following HTTP request:

Simple CSV:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=40.756041,-73.986939&output=csv&sensor=false
```

More Complex XML:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=40.756041,-73.986939&output=xml&sensor=false
```

Simply change the "q" parameter with your latitude,longitude.

Note that the Google Maps API has a limit of 15,000 request per IP address per day. ([Google Maps API FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_limit))

Comment: Oh nice, any idea on ToS for that? Can I do 40000 of these overnight? :)

Comment: You can do 15,000 per IP address per day: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_limit

Answer (score 5):

What about doing reverse geocoding with the Google Maps API?

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#ReverseGeocoding

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [bulk Reverse Geocoder](http://www.batchgeocode.com/reverse/) which, internally, uses the Google Maps API to reverse geocode an entire series (in a CSV file) of latitude and longitude pairs.

It would make this fairly easy.